# Не могу получить broadcast

Tags: java, android-sdk, android, android-fragment

Проблема в том что во фрагменте не ловит broadcast. Во фрагменте так его регистрирую. Но в onResume получаю null. Пошуршав интернет, ничего внятного не нашёл. Но если вынести в отдельный файл, и зарегать в манифесте то тогда всё отлично ловиться. Тестирую на API 18. В чем может быть проблема?

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("logba", "onReceive : ");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(KeyChain.ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED)) {
            Log.d("logba", "onReceive : keychain");
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("logba", "onResume : register" + getContext().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(KeyChain.ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED)));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d("logba", "onPause : unregister");
    getContext().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: `в onResume получаю null` - расшифруйте пожалуйста.

Comment: getContext().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(KeyChain.ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED))); - вот этот код  возвращает null;

Comment: Это нормально. Прочитайте, что должен возвращать этот метод в оф. документации.

Comment: Ладно, фиг с ним с этим registerReceiver, хотя в нете пишут что он может возвращать null когда фильтра нет, например хочешь получить заряд батареи, а прилага стоит на телевизоре где нет батареи. Меня больше волнует почему не ловиться броадкаст, при этом если сделать отдельный файл и зарегистрировать его в манифесте, всё работает как часы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл проблему. Когда я вызываю этот код(см.ниже) открывается KeyChain activity и мой фрагмент уходит в pause. Когда был установлен сертификат и был показан toast об успешной установки сертификата, мой фрагмент до сих пор находится в pause. Поэтому он пропускает этот broadcast и прекрасно его ловит в отдельном файле.

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, certificate);
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, name);
startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALL_CA_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

ВЫ можете не получать сообщения в BroadCast только в том случае, если ваш фрагмент будет в состоянии **onPause()** и это норма и правильное поведение BroadCast. Если вам необходим BroadCast, который постоянно будет отлавливать сообщения, то реализовывать его необходимо в отдельном фале, как вы и писали и описать этот BroadCast в манифесте и назначив ему нужный фильтр, на который он будет реагировать, другого не дано.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(KeyChain.ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED));
```

ну и `getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);`

это может быть связано с тем, что ты регистрируешь ресивер в контексте всего приложения, а генерируешь событие в контексте активности.

Comment: Чего я только не пробовал, не помогает. Написал на b.android.com посмотрим что ответят.